# Microsoft Account in TestCafe test. - "Your security info change is still pending"

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are using TestCafe to log into a WebSite that is secured with Azure Active Directory.

The security info for the Microsoft accounts has been updated (alternative email was to a previous tester's account). That has put something of a block on the account. However that block is temporary when I log in normally with either Chrome or Edge.

The first time with either browser I got a page saying

[image]

After pressing the "Next" button I was able to continue to the site logged in with the Test account and it acted as expected.

However when I run any tests in TestCafe that use those accounts they **still** get the "Your security info change is still pending". Is this a scenario others have found themselves in?

I did try and record a new Test that pressed the "Next" button but that is not working (for a probably unrelated reason) I get the error message "check web address http://192.168.1.30:49763 is correct"

Comment: You can try running your tests with the [--disable-page-caching](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--disable-page-caching) option. If this doesn't help, please share your test and an instruction on how to reproduce this issue with a regular Microsoft account.

Answer (score 1):

As Vladimir suggested I swicthed to a regular account created in our Active Directory rather than one  from outlook.com. I never tried the --disable-page-caching option